# AngularFire Route Authentication by user role

Tags: angularjs, authentication, firebase, angularfire

I am currently using Firebase's email & password user registration/login system, and the [security component](https://github.com/firebase/angularfire-seed/blob/master/app/components/security/security.js) from the AngularFire-seed repo. This lets me add authentication to routes like so:

```
.config(function($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider

        .whenAuthenticated('/profile', {
            title: 'Profile',
            templateUrl: '/app/components/profile/profile.html',
            controller: 'ProfileController'
        })

})
```

What I would like to do now is not only require authentication to access a particular route, but require admin access, e.g. to the `'/admin'` route, so a regular authenticated user couldn't see the page at all. Could someone explain the best way of achieving this?

I thought of adding a user profile section to my Firebase, then looking up that when the route is accessed but maybe there's a better way. I can also set up my Firebase security rules so that only I can write data, but this wouldn't stop people from accessing the page and reading it in the first place.

I've googled this several times and couldn't find anything related to user role authentication with AngularFire.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You've essentially asked how to build a roles-based security system. As you can imagine, that's a broad topic. The steps here would be:  1) make the users' roles read-only. 2) use security rules on the data which access the roles to control access (e.g. `".write": "root.child('roles').child(auth.uid).val() > 2"`), 3) change the whenAuthenticated service to read the roles data and compare instead of just checking for auth !== null by using $requireAuth()

Comment: Thanks Kato, I'll give it a go. I usually use Express to handle this but was interested to know how it works in Firebase

Comment: have u solved this? @Daniel7912 i want to do the same thing with firebase and angularjs